# linq subtract within select statement

Tags: linq, lambda, subtraction

I want to distribute values of my summed quantities over multiple date ranges, which overlap.  So,
the end result of this query is simply 2 records with overlapping date ranges.  But, the current query just duplicates the values (quantities) in each.  But, I want to place the data in the first record only as it's the first record within the same date range as the 2nd record, so the second record quantity (AllocQty) I want to be 0.  right now it's coming up with equal quantities for both records, and they are in the same date range.  I am modifying existing code, so I'm wondering if theres a way to just modify the code to somehow subtract the sum from the first group, so it won't be placed in the 2nd group.  Is there a way to do that without rewriting this substantially?

```
from c in com
  join b in all on c.SKU equals b.SKU into ps
  from b in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
  .Where(x => x == null || (c.StartDate <= x.FinishDate && c.EndDate >= x.FinishDate)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new
  {
      ComId = c.ComId,
      metadatafromtablec,
      etc...
      ...
      AllocQty = b != null ? b.VDC_Alloc : 0,  //Here I want this value to be zero in the 2nd overlapping group (startdate)

  } into x

//It groups by every single field except for the calculated sum of the VAlloc //and KAlloc quantities

  group x by new { x.ComId, x.ComType, x.CustType, x.CustrId, x.SKU, x.StartDate, x.EndDate} into grp
  select new CommitmentView
  {
      CommId = grp.Key.ComId,
      ...
      ...
      AllocQty = grp.Sum(r => r.AllocQty),
      TotalAllocQty = grp.Sum(r => r.AllocQty) + grp.Sum(r => r.KAllocQty),
  } into cv
  orderby cv.SKU ascending
  select cv
```

table c (com):

| COMID | COM_TYPE | CUSTTYPE | CUSTRID | SKU | START_DATE | END_DATE | VDC_CQ | KDC_CQ | COMSTATUS | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_BY | UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/1/2021 | 4/12/2021 | 2400 | 1560 | APPROVED | humak | 2/9/2021 3:26:18 PM | chrj | 2/23/2021 11:43:41 AM |
| 107 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/7/2021 | 4/13/2021 | 288 | 84 | DRAFT | chrj | 2/8/2021 3:28:24 PM | chrj | 2/24/2021 6:27:51 PM |

table b (all):

| EVENT_ID | LINE_ID | SKU | CUSTRID | ALLOCQTY | SUBMISSION_STATUS | ERROR_CODE | ERROR_DESCRIPTION | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_BY | UPDATED_DATE | FinishDate | UOM | CUSTOMER_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100150 | 5344 | 111872 | 3 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/23/2021 6:11:04 PM |  | 2/23/2021 6:11:04 PM | 4/13/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100148 | 5342 | 111872 | 3 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/8/2021 3:23:27 PM |  | 2/8/2021 3:23:27 PM | 2/9/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100149 | 5343 | 111872 | 3 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/9/2021 1:58:30 PM |  | 2/9/2021 1:58:30 PM | 2/9/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4952 | 111872 | 160 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4954 | 111872 | 129 | 24 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4956 | 111872 | 228 | 60 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4958 | 111872 | 218 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4960 | 111872 | 167 | 36 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4961 | 111872 | 158 | 120 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4964 | 111872 | 76 | 36 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4966 | 111872 | 163 | 24 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |
| 100139 | 4969 | 111872 | 174 | 12 | SCHEDULED |  |  | chrj | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM |  | 2/5/2021 4:38:46 PM | 2/11/2021 | C | BCL |

Current Output:

| COMID | COM_TYPE | CUSTTYPE | CUSTRID | SKU | START_DATE | END_DATE | VDC_CQ | KDC_CQ | COMSTATUS | TOTALALLOCQTY | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_BY | UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/7/2021 | 4/13/2021 | 288 | 84 | DRAFT | 372 | chrj | 2/8/2021 3:28:24 PM | chrj | 2/24/2021 6:27:51 PM |
| 108 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/1/2021 | 4/12/2021 | 2400 | 1560 | APPROVED | 360 | humak | 2/9/2021 3:26:18 PM | chrj | 2/23/2021 11:43:41 AM |

You can see the quantity of 360 is 'duplicated' in both records.  There was a change desired by management to allow these records to overlap by date (You can see start date to end date
overlaps from 2/7/2021 to 4/12/2021.  So, now the 360 should be in the record with comid of 108, and the remaining quantity of 12 should be in record with comid of 107 like this:

Desired Output:

| COMID | COM_TYPE | CUSTTYPE | CUSTRID | SKU | START_DATE | END_DATE | VDC_CQ | KDC_CQ | COMSTATUS | TOTALALLOCQTY | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | UPDATED_BY | UPDATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/7/2021 | 4/13/2021 | 288 | 84 | DRAFT | 12 | chrj | 2/8/2021 3:28:24 PM | chrj | 2/24/2021 6:27:51 PM |
| 108 | RETAIL | BCL | 0 | 111872 | 2/1/2021 | 4/12/2021 | 2400 | 1560 | APPROVED | 360 | humak | 2/9/2021 3:26:18 PM | chrj | 2/23/2021 11:43:41 AM |

It should distribute the quantity between the records that overlap and the FinishDate that's within the range of the start date and end date.  You can see there is one record
from table b that is dated 4/13/2021, so that's the only record that should be in the output of comid == 107.

Comment: Is an [mre] possible? A simple list with only few element showing each edge case: no overlap of AB, B inside of A range, AB same start, AB same end. And the different result you expect. With a clear expected result. I will not care about "_rewriting this substantially_", it has to give the right result, right? You won't pickup the wrong child just because that one was closer. Im not saying rewritte everything, but could have have a clear view on what is the correct way before focusing on a code that don't work.

Comment: The exmaple don't need all the properties, just 2 for the range, one for quantity and one for grouping.

Comment: Just in case `Where` usage looks wrong.

Comment: Adding sample data and cleaning up now

Comment: Added Sample data.  Will add sample output as well if needed

Comment: Added sample input tables, and current and expected output.  Any idea?  Also, I did attempt several times to simply add the allocqty at the end, so leaving it set to zero in the grouping join, then adding it at the end.  Ran into a few roadblocks, and it was 2 am, so I gave up, will try that method tomorrow, as in theory it should work, as I will just subtract the values from a list of quantities, so, if the dates overlap, the next record will take whatever is remaining from the quantities. In theory, that is!!